# Application tried to present modally an active controller iOS 6.0.2

Tags: ios, ipad, modalviewcontroller

I am getting following error when I try to present a UIViewController modally.

> "Application tried to present modally an active controller".

I have read many posts on this in stackoverflow. Which explains about this error.
I am aware that, this exception is thrown when UIViewController which is already presented, is attempted to show modally again.

My application logic is:

When app goes to background. I dismiss modal view controller using

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]
```

When app comes back to foreground, I show the controller again

```
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:NO]
```

This logic works fine on iPad with iOS 6.0.1, but fails with iPad Mini with iOS 6.0.2.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I changed the implementation to this:
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

Still same exception is generated.

I checked the presentedViewController property, interestingly it still holds the reference to the view controller even after dismissing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution is to use `presentViewControllerAnimated:completion:nil` **and** `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` for iOS6 or try to present the view controller after some delay *(Call by method of `NSTimer`).*

```
[self presentViewController:YourVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**and**

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YourVC completion:nil];
```

Comment: yes, looks like that is the problem.
I also need to support iOS 5.1.1, so may be I need to write conditional code specific to iOS versions.

Comment: I gave animation NO. Still same problem persists. Even I replaced the deprecated methods.

Comment: I am also having same problem

Comment: Same problem here too...Any fix?